# Prove that the given function is harmonic.(Complex Analysis).

Tags: complex-analysis

We're given a function $ln(x^{2} + y^{2})$ , we need to prove that the given function is harmonic in every domain that doesn't contain origin.

What I tried :

Let $z= x +i y$ , so we write $Logz$ as :

$Logz = ln|z| + i(Argz)$ ,

=> $Logz = \dfrac{ln(x^{2} + y^{2})}{2} + i\:(tan^{-1}\dfrac{y}{x})$ ,

Now , we know that $Logz$ is differentiable for $|z|>0$ and $- \pi < Argz < \pi$,

Since , $Logz$ is differentiable , => $u(x,y)=\dfrac{ln(x^{2} + y^{2})}{2}$ and $v(x,y)=tan^{-1}\dfrac{y}{x}$ are continuous and are differentiable , for $|z|>0$ , i.e , $x^{2} + y^{2} >0$ , thus $z \neq 0$ ,

And then we show that $ u_{xx} + u_{yy}=0$ , and hence $u(x,y)$ is harmonic.

Is this correct ?
Could anyone help ?

Comment: The real and imaginary parts of a holomorphic function are harmonic; this follows from Cauchy-Riemann eqns.

Comment: Your $v$ isn't well-defined on $\mathbb{C} \setminus 0$. What happens when $x = 0$? (In fact, $u$ doesn't have a harmonic conjugate on $\mathbb{C} \setminus 0$.) It's a better idea just to compute $u''_{xx} + u''_{yy}$.